# Join on rows that not in other table

Tags: mysql

I want to show all locations that not used in table 2 and the locations where is stock 0.

I have the query for table 2:

```
SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE stock = 0
```

table 1

```
loc_id  lc_number
1       800
2       801
3       802
4       803
5       804
```

table 2

```
loc_id     stock
2          3
5          0
```

output:

```
loc_id
1
3
4
5
```

but how can i combine my query with the other table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.lc_number
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.loc_id = t2.loc_id
WHERE t2.loc_id is null or t2.stock = 0
```

Comment: how can i get the lc_number instead of t1.loc_id?

Comment: Just replace it in the select part.